# Issue findViewById using R.java resources

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, resources, textview

I have two activities namely MainActivity and DisplayMessageActivity. MainActivity is a app launcher and the first UI which contains only two components : **EditText** and **Button** .
And DisplayMessageActivity has only one component **TextView** with default string defined. I just want to change/set the **TextView**'s text value which was typed in **EditText** field and when the **Button** is clicked.

`TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typed_text);`

returns null pointer in DisplayMessageActivity which was navigated by MainActivity's intent call. I could able to set and get the text in MainActivity without a problem. Please help me :)

@codeMagic : Thanks :) Here is the xml 
`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/typed_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/typed_text"/>
```

`

The onCreate method in DisplayMessageActivity :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    //TextView textView = new TextView(this); - This works

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typed_text); // null pointer

    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);



    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }   

}
```

Comment: you must pass value of `EditText` to next activity with intent and get that from second class, more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217997/how-to-send-a-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android/20218116#20218116

Comment: Make sure that `typed_text` is the `id` of a `TextView` in the xml file you inflate with `setContentView()` in `DisplayMessageActivity`. If you think it is then please post that xml and the `onCreate()` of that `Activity`.

Comment: @codeMagic : Thanks :) Here is the xml

Comment: You didn't post `onCreate()` of `DisplayMessageActivity`. In there do you have `setContentView(R.layout.nameOfFileWithThatTextView)`?

Comment: Kindly upload the code of `DisplayMessageActivity` for our better understanding.

Comment: Is the `TextView` you posted above inside `activity_display_message.xml`?

Comment: Yes @codeMagic. Good news , the code works now fine. In order to post here I cleaned up the code a bit. And I defined `setContentView' in the beginning. Being a novice it is not intuitive

Comment: Ok, glad its working now

Answer (score 0):

When you start DisplayMessageActivity, use `intent.putExtra()` to pass on the input from your EditText.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

This is probably exactly what you need!

Comment: This is exactly I am using to train myself. Here the contentView(textView) is manually created. I just wanted a TextView in the xml and want to change it.

Comment: Just like the previous answer, this has nothing to do with the current problem